# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException on ideone

Tags: java

This is my first code with java .when I tested it on Ideone. It showed:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Hw2_p4.main(Main.java:22)
```

I searched for answers but I didn't get the problem cause or how to fix it.
the code runs on eclipse normally

Here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Hw2_p4 {

    static void swap(String[] A, int a, int b) {
        String temp = A[a];
        A[a] = A[b];
        A[b] = temp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = sc.nextInt(), m = sc.nextInt();
        int i, j, k, l, counter = 0;

        String[] name = new String[16];
        String[][] notalong = new String[120][2];
        String[] temp = new String[120];
        boolean[][] A = new boolean[120][2];

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            name[i] = sc.next();
        }

        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                notalong[i][j] = sc.next();
            }
        }

        int flag = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                flag = 0;
                for (k = i + 1; k < m; k++) {
                    for (l = 0; l < 2; l++) {
                        if (notalong[i][j].compareToIgnoreCase(notalong[k][l]) == 0 && A[i][j] == false && A[k][l] == false) {
                            A[k][l] = true;
                            flag = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (flag == 1) {
                    A[i][j] = true;
                    counter++;
                } else if (flag == 0 && A[i][0] == false && A[i][1] == false) {
                    A[i][j] = true;
                    counter++;
                }
            }

        }

        System.out.println(n - counter);
        int x = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                if (A[i][j] == false) {
                    temp[x++] = notalong[i][j];
                    A[i][j] = true;

                    for (k = i + 1; k < m; k++) {
                        for (l = 0; l < 2; l++) {
                            if (notalong[i][j].compareToIgnoreCase(notalong[k][l]) == 0 && A[k][l] == false) {
                                A[k][l] = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //compare not along with names
        int found = 1;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            found = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                for (k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                    if (name[i].compareToIgnoreCase(notalong[j][k]) == 0) {
                        found = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (found == 0) {
                temp[x++] = name[i];
            }
        }

        //sorting lexicographically
        boolean swapp = true;
        for (i = 0; i < x && swapp; i++) {
            swapp = false;
            for (j = 0; j < x - i - 1; j++) {
                if (temp[j].compareToIgnoreCase(temp[j + 1]) > 0) {
                    swap(temp, j, j + 1);
                    swapp = true;
                }
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            System.out.println(temp[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is you don't have enough input for `sc.next()` This is what the error means.

Comment: I suggest you use the formatter in your IDE to make your code easier to read.

Comment: what does it mean not enough input for sc.next()? would you please explain more

Comment: You are calling `sc.nextInt()` when there is nothing to read.

Comment: you mean that I need  sc.nextLine(); after each scan for an integer or string

Comment: "The code runs normally on eclipse" : do you mean that the Exception is thrown when you execute your code outside Eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideone is not interactive. You have to click on `Specify input` and enter all of your input in there before you run the application. What you are seeing is an exception because `System.in` has an "end of file" status.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to protect `sc.next()` with `cs.hasNext()`:

```
while (!sc.hasNext()) {
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
int n = sc.nextInt();
```

However since you read the input in many location throughout your code try using `Scanner.nextLine()` preferably printing to the console, what is the input you are expecting next. `nextLine()` will read all the input until the user presses ENTER, which is a nicer 'user journey' than simply constantly reading keyboard and passing it to `System.in`.

```
System.out.print("Please enter your favourite number : "); //NB print and space is last
String input = sc.nextLine();
int favNumber = Double.parseDouble(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

the way that Ideone gives input to your code is different from the way your IDE(or you)gives input.
so you should probably figure out how does Ideone gives input and then fix your code to that way of inputs.